# An efficient way to shuffle a JSON array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, shuffle

Which would be the best way to do it? Right now, I convert my `JSONArray` to an `ArrayList` of a custom class, use `Collections.shuffle()` to perform the action, and convert back to `JSONArray`, which seems to be too much overhead.

The answer may be just to implement a
[Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for it, but my guess is that this may be already done so I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel.
I looked at the standard [JSON api](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [Google's Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) but they don't seem to have any implementation.

There are also simple options for a standard array [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742754/randomize-or-shuffle-an-array) that could be easily ported to java, but I would gladly hear your input. I am amazed that the query http://www.google.com/search?q=java+shuffle+jsonarray did not flood me with methods.

Comment: "seems to be too much overhead" - have you profiled it, or is this just a guess? If it's just a guess, profile it and then determine if it's really an issue at all.

Comment: I understand what you say, but for now the arrays are very small, so it is not really noticeable, but I want to make sure the code remains scalable for when the number of arrays (and size) increase.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for posting an answer to my own question, but right now, since there was no out-of-the-box quick solution, I'm implementing my own static shuffle function based on the code from this post: [Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array-in-android/1520212#1520212) . Still looking forward to hear about the best implementation. This is what I did:

```
public static JSONArray shuffleJsonArray (JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = array.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Object object = array.get(j);
          array.put(j, array.get(i));
          array.put(i, object);
        }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method works great, but don't forget to:

```
rnd.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

so that the results are unique each time.

Sorry for the new answer, I don't have enough rep to post a comment :/

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON library that doesn't require you to convert to some kind of JSON data structure when the language already has perfectly good `List` and `Map` interfaces built in.

http://code.google.com/p/prebake/source/browse/trunk/code/src/org/prebake/js/JsonSink.java and http://code.google.com/p/prebake/source/browse/trunk/code/src/org/prebake/js/JsonSource.java for example.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the links. I will look into them further, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation about it.