# how to randomize questions in the quiz every time the user play using json array in android

Tags: java, javascript, android, json, random

im developing a simple quiz, where i have 50 questions stored..my problem is, i cannot randomize the questions, it should be randomize everytime the user will play, and only 10 questions to display...please help me...ive done using this [An efficient way to shuffle a JSON array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531130/an-efficient-way-to-shuffle-a-json-array-in-java) but it dont workS!!!!!thank you so much for you help!

```
public class Question1 extends Activity {



Intent menu = null;
BufferedReader bReader = null;
static JSONArray quesList = null;
static int index = 50;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question10);

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                finish();
                loadQuestions();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Question1.this,
                        Question2.class);
                Question1.this.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();

}

private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
    try {



        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }

        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());


    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            bReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
        }

    }

}

public static JSONArray shuffleJsonArray (JSONArray quesList) throws JSONException {
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = quesList.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
          int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
          // Simple swap
          Object object = quesList.get(j);
          quesList.put(j, quesList.get(i));
          quesList.put(i, object);
        }
    return quesList;
}
```

Comment: where are you calling shuffleJsonArray()

Comment: you can generate question nos randomly and save them in an array then use that array to display the question randomly??

Comment: @Shiv yes. questions must randomly display everytime the user will start the game.

Comment: see i am also new dont know about json and all but what i am saying is you can start a loop which generates question no's randomly and save them in an array and then use that array to bind or display questions..that will be random na

Comment: this is my updated question and i modify it a little and it WORKS!!!!! ive just use this code..public static JSONArray getQuesList()throws JSONException{
  
    Random rnd = new Random();
         
         for (int i = quesList.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
           int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
           // Simple swap
           Object object = quesList.get(j);
           quesList.put(j, quesList.get(i));
           quesList.put(i, object);
         }
   return quesList;

Comment: did my trick help you :P ??

Comment: ok then i am posting it as an answer tick right if it does worked for you :)

Comment: @naveen thanks for making me analyse ur question...it let me think if i really should call shuffleJsonArray..hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

you can start a loop which generates question no's randomly and save them in an array and then use that array to bind or display questions..that will be random....