# Randomize array of questions while reading from text file android

Tags: android, arrays, random, arc4random

This is a android quiz app code snippet which load the question from text file.
I want to shuffle the question and answer  after every next click so how can i implement random function ?
https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun/blob/master/src/ssk/quizfun/QuizFunActivity.java

https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun/blob/master/res/raw/questions.txt

```
 private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {
        InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
        StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
        String aJsonLine = null;
        while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            quesString.append(aJsonLine);
        }
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
        JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
        quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                "Num Questions " + quesList.length());
        } catch (Exception e){

        } finally {
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
            }

        }


    }







https://github.com/gitssk/quizfun/blob/master/src/ssk/quizfun/QuizFunActivity.java
```

Comment: oviosuly you can shuffle with  Collections.shuffle

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: `Collections.shuffle` on a `JSONArray`? Is that even possible?

Comment: You could have a look at [Aleadam's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531130/an-efficient-way-to-shuffle-a-json-array-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

I will refrain from posting much code because I think you should attempt it on your own. It is seriously not that tough. I will give you an approach though.

You have `quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");`. So `quesList` is the list of questions that is a `JSONArray`. You want to shuffle this. Just do this:

1. Get the length of the `quesList` array. Let's call it `len`.
2. Create a simple arrayList called `quesOrder` containing integers `0 to len`.

   ```
   List<Integer> quesOrder = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
   {
    quesOrder.add(i);
   }
   ```

Once you have the `quesOrder` array. Just do `Collections.shuffle(quesOrder);`. Now when you get questions from your `quesList` array, just get the index from `quesOrder` list. And you will have a randomized selection. Put it together in a function for convenience.