# java randomize indices in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indices

I have looked at Randomize or shuffle an array [Randomize or shuffle an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742754/randomize-or-shuffle-an-array)

I am not sure if this is the best approach to make.

I want to randomize the indices of an array with 3 items.

12
4
5

```
int numbers[] = new int[3];
```

I tried using the Maths.Random

int randomoption2 = opmin + (int)(Math.random() * ((opmax - opmin) + 1));

but I then have an issue with repetition of the indices values. What is the best approach to randomize the indices  so there is no repetition .

eg

```
a[1] = 2;
```

I don't want two elements in the array coming back with an indices of one

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Shuffle.html

```
public class randomorder {

        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
            randomorder();  
            System.out.println(randomorder());
        }

        public static ArrayList randomorder(){
            ArrayList nums = new ArrayList();
            nums.add(1);
            nums.add(2);
            nums.add(3);

            Collections.shuffle(nums);
            return nums;
        }
    }
```

I now need to store each of the numbers in variables so they can be outputted

System.out.println(options[0]);

Comment: If you need to shuffle randomly, you can use Collections#shuffle

Comment: hi thanks could you provide a simple example please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://ideone.com/Zd365):

```
Integer[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Zd365)

It uses the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)  internally. This is an efficient shuffling algorithm that won't give you duplicates.

**Related**

- [Java's Collections.shuffle is doing what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249520/javas-collections-shuffle-is-doing-what)
- [How to convert int[] to Integer[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/how-to-convert-int-to-integer-in-java)
- [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)

Comment: Doesn't work with `int[]`, just tested. The array of primitives doesn't get shuffeld. Works fine with `Integer[]`... (To my own surprise)

Comment: And now with an array of `int[]`, please :P - Casting from `int[]` to `Integer[]` obviously doesn't work ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D: You are right. You can't have a `List<int>`. Instead you get a `List<int[]>`! The solution is to use `Integer[]` instead. Related: [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should).

Comment: @alex: What do you mean by "then need to print out the values so each System.out.println contains a value". Is this for homework?

Comment: its a piece of software I am writing. I have everything finished button the random number generator function. It is written in android but I wanted to separate the android framework from the Java code. I need the numbers that are shuffled to go into three radio buttons

Comment: um just imagine their 3 System.out.pritnln() statements. I know where to go from there.

Comment: I just want three System.out.println to output the values after they have been shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep three booleans through an array of booleans. Once you hit 0, 1, or 2 index set them to true.

Choose a random position and do while(boolean[number chosen] == true) redo your random choice.

Comment: This is close to what I'd do if the Collections answer wasn't feasible.