# 1120: Access of undefined property shuffledArray

Tags: actionscript-3

Please can you help me out I am new to as3 and I am trying to create a shuffled deck using the Fisher-Yates Algorithm. When I run the code with ctrl-enter it compiles with no errors but when I try to output it with trace(); it comes back with:

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 6   1120: Access of undefined property shuffledArray.

Like I said I am new to this and it will be me doing something very stupid but all the same i'm stuck.

Here is the code

```
package src.CardDeck
{
    public class CardDeck
    {
        public var allCards:Array = [];
        public var cardNames:Array;
        public var cardValues:Array;
        public var gameType:String;
        public var drawnCards:uint = 0;

        public function CardDeck(game:String)
        {
            gameType = game;
            cardNames = ["Ace","Two","Three",
                         "Four","Five","Six",
                         "Seven","Eight","Nine",
                         "Ten","Jack","Queen","King"];
            if(gameType == "texasholdem")
            {
                cardValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10];
            }
            makeSuit("Spade");
            makeSuit("Heart");
            makeSuit("Diamond");
            makeSuit("Club");
        }
        function makeSuit(suitString:String):void
        {
            var card:Object;

            for(var i:uint = 0; i < cardNames.length; i++)
            {
                card = {};
                card.cardType = suitString;
                card.cardName = cardNames[i];
                card.cardValue = cardValues[i];
                card.isDrawn = false;
                allCards.push(card);
            }
        }

        public function shuffleFisherYates():Array 
        {
            var shuffledArray:Array = [];
            var randomCardIndex: int;
            do 
            {
                randomCardIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* allCards.length);
                shuffledArray.push(allCards[randomCardIndex]); // add to mix
                allCards.splice(randomCardIndex,1); // remove from deck
            }while(allCards.length); // Meaning while allCards.length != 0
            return shuffledArray;


        }
    }
}
```

and here is the .fla actions layer

```
import src.CardDeck.CardDeck;

var deck:CardDeck = new CardDeck("texasholdem");
trace(shuffledArray);
```

I know its probably something silly but i'm struggling.

Thanks in advance!

Paul

Answer (score 1):

```
var deck:CardDeck = new CardDeck("texasholdem");
trace(shuffledArray);
```

This doesn't work because `shuffledArray` isn't defined there.

Try :

```
var deck:CardDeck = new CardDeck("texasholdem");
var array:Array = deck.shuffleFisherYates();

for(var i:int=0; i<array.length; i++)
{    
    trace(array[i].cardName);
    trace(array[i].cardType);
    trace(array[i].cardValue);
    trace(array[i].isDrawn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works but now im getting [object Object], 52 times?

Comment: [object Object] is what a generic object prints out as. If you look in your code where you create a card object, you're using a generic object. The line of code I'm referring to is: "card = {};"

Comment: Like @mitim said you would need to trace the actual elements from that array.

Comment: How would I ago about tracing the actual elements from the array as I have tried everything including staring at the screen blankly wondering if I'm ever going to be able to grasp this(head scratch). Thanks From, Complete Beginner

Answer (score 0):

"shuffledArray" is a property inside of your CardDeck object. To access public methods and properties within it, you need to use the dot syntax:

```
trace(deck.shuffleFisherYates());
```

However, depending on what you are doing, you may not need to really be accessing the array directly, if your CardDeck object is meant to control the entire deck.

Comment: This is driving me insane what am i doing wrong I have been at this for hours with no joy (would cue hair pull but there's none left). Can one of you please help I have done everything that you guys said and still bloody [object Object]

Comment: you need to go into the actual object and access the properties of it. Looking at your code, each "card" object you create you've given it a "cardType", "cardName", and "cardValue" property. For each "card" object you can then access each property by using the dot notation, such as cardObject.cardType, cardObject.cardName, and cardObject.cardValue. I am guessing this is what you want to print out.

Comment: sorry I should of specified I only want to test the shuffling function that has been created and make sure that it is sending back a shuffled deck. when I comment out the shuffle function and trace(my card object); it returns the list of cards from Ace of Spades through the 52 cards. I just want to print out the same list after it has been passed through the shuffle function.

Comment: right, so what you're saying makes sense: you want to print out the array of cards before and after the shuffle to make sure that they are indeed shuffled. Printing out the array directly reveals all your card objects...but summarized/shortened as just '[Object object]'. That is useless to you as you want to see the value of each card object. Thus you can make a loop that goes in to each object and prints out the specific properties as mentioned in my previous comment to see the values.

Comment: Im new to this and have no idea where I would put this loop and where to begin, any help would me great:)

Comment: hm... I can see this getting out of hand and going on quite long (and off track of the original question). But you'd put it...wherever you want to print it?

Comment: Okay thanks for your help im going to get back to the books because I am no where near ready for this. Again thanks for your time and help:)