# is it possible to shuffle that three arrays everytime the game starts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

i created three arrays and each of them has their own sets of questions in it. is it possible to shuffle that three arrays everytime the game starts? so that the user will have to answer different sets of question everytime he clicks for a new game.

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

See for example:

- [Randomize or shuffle an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742754/randomize-or-shuffle-an-array)
- [as3 random array - randomize array - actionscript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980657/as3-random-array-randomize-array-actionscript-3)

The second one has a nice cheeky little use of `Array.sort()`:

```
var arr:Array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function randomize (a:*, b:*):int
{
    return (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1;
}

trace(arr.sort(randomize));
```

Comment: dont understand sir. lets say i created three arrays like this.

Comment: dont understand sir. lets say i created three arrays like this. var arr:array =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; var arr2:array =[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]; var arr3:array =[a1, b2, c3, d4, e5, f6, g7, h8, i9, j9]; let say these arrays contain different sets of questions, what code will i use to shuffle this three arrays and pick one array for the users questions to be shown?.

Answer (score 0):

To shuffle the 3 arrays you could create 3 other arrays that will serve to hold the shuffled values.

```
var arr1:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sorted1:Array = new Array(arr1.length);
var arr2:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sorted2:Array = new Array(arr2.length);
var arr3:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var sorted3:Array = new Array(arr3.length);

randomPos:Number = 0;
```

you could then create a function that takes the value from one array and place it into a new shuffled array.

```
function shuffleArray(x, y){
    for(var i:int = 0; i < y.length; i++){
        randomPos = int(Math.random() * x.length);
        y[i] = x.splice(randomPos, 1)[0];
    }
}
```

Then you would call the suffleArray function on each set of arrays:

```
shuffleArray(arr1, sorted1);
shuffleArray(arr2, sorted2);
shuffleArray(arr3, sorted3);
```

I hope this helps.